# Unobtrusive validation warnings (not errors)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

How would I go about building a warning level notification on top of the built in unobtrusive validation?

Totally made up example:  I'm allowing people to specify how long they'd wait for a table from the start of their reservation.  It has to be between 0 and 12 hours (no negative waits, and nothing past closing time), but one might also want to ask "are you sure" about a 5 hour wait?

Obviously you could do this in a one-off fashion on a field by field basis, but I'd like to have it based on data model attributes, since that's where I'd have the "between 0 and 12" validation.

So, off the top of my head, I can see the need for something that extends ValidationAttribute and implements IClientValidatable.  I'd also need to add my validation method to validator in a custom JavaScript file.  Is that it?